# Filtering duplicates in DAX based on variables

Tags: dax, powerquery, powerpivot

Not sure if this problem is better addressed in DAX (powerpivot) or powerquery.

Anyways the goal remove certain duplicates of material numbers based on variables in columns Q,P and O. See below material number duplications need to be filtered on incorrect lead-time values. for example material number 6928 needs the row 2,3,4,5 removed or filters as this has the correct lead-time of 7 days in rows 6-9. this can be verified by column R (regular vendor).
happy to share the file if it helps.

[image: raw data]

manual filter result outcome should = this

[image]

if you need more information, please let me know. thanks

Comment: You might want to remove the powerPOINT tag and add powerPIVOT instead.

Comment: thanks, should have used my glasses

Comment: Revised question as it was not clear

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking. Do you want to remove the rows that don't have an X in the R column and don't have matching PDT and PDT_3 values? (My understanding is that an X in R indicates the PDT and PDT_3 values match.) In your example of what the outcome should be, you also kept rows that don't meet those conditions (Material 222179) . I don't see how you filtered to include those last three rows. Do you somehow want to still keep rows of  certain material numbers that don't have an X in the R column and don't have matching PDT and PDT_3 values like that? If so what's the logic flow?

Comment: Hi Marc  - Sorry this table is a merge of various tables. The first has material number with lead-time and reorder points, MLS and procurement type. From there a second table is merged adding in R (regular vendor) and PDT3 which is where the procurement lead-time is kept. This action creates some duplicates in which I want to keep records where PDT3 = PDT and R keep. Or no R value, keep PDT value. From there i add in another merge sheet which is usage defining posting date and quantity on that date. I guess I am asking is during my merges can I remove duplicates based on values in power query

Comment: or just filter using DAX with all the data together.

Comment: to clarify the duplicates are not the posting date with values as sometimes there is consumption of the material on the same day. The duplication seems to be where there is another PDT_3 value assigned to the material number during the merge, two values, different suppliers. I only want to keep one. if it has an X in column R keep that value if no X value keep PDT_3 where PDT_3 = PDT or no PDT_3 keep PDT.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I needed to clean my data before merging, rather than cleaning afterward.

I found the duplications in one of my merged tables and removed them by filters. Once I refreshed my data queries, the duplications I wanted removed had gone.